# Explode string php

Tags: php

```
$string = "|1|2|3|4|";
$array = explode("|", $string, -1); 

foreach ($array as $part) {
    echo $part."-";
}
```

I use -1 in explode to skip the last "|" in string. But how do I do if I also want to skip the first "|"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to Strip `|` from the beginning and end of a string and then can use the explode.

```
$string = "|1|2|3|4|";
$array = explode("|", trim($string,'|'));
```

Comment: +1 for a very simple solution. Perhaps you tell Daniel how your codes work. :)

Answer (score 4):

[**`preg_split()`**](http://fr.php.net/preg_split), and its `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` option, should do just the trick, here.

And great advantage : it'll skip empty parts even in the middle of the string -- and not just at the beginning or end of it.

The following portion of code :

```
$string = "|1|2|3|4|";
$parts = preg_split('/\|/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($parts);
```

Will give you this resulting array :

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '4' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

take a substring first, then explode.
http://codepad.org/4CLZqkle

```
<?php

$string = "|1|2|3|4|";
$string = substr($string,1,-1);
$array = explode("|", $string); 

foreach ($array as $part) {
    echo $part."-";
}
echo PHP_EOL ;

/* or use implode to join */
echo implode("-",$array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_shift()` to remove the first element from the array.